# How to get the installation path of a XULRunner application in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, installation, xul, xulrunner

Assume we have a XULRunner application installed at `C:\myapp\`, that is, `application.ini` file etc. are in that directory.
My question is: how to get the installation path (`C:\myapp\`) in the app's JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for XULrunner, `CurProcD` is usually the installation path:

```
var path = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
             .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
             .get("CurProcD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path;
```

Failing that, you might also try `resource:app`.

Ref: [File I/O](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O) at MDN.

Comment: Thank you! `CurProcD` works for me. MDN says that `CurProcD` is "Current working directory (usually the application's installation directory)", but even if I lunch xulrunner in another directory, I still get the application's installation directory from `CurProcD`. Does xulrunner always change CWD to the application's installation directory?

Comment: By the way, when I try `resource:app`, I get an exeption [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]". It seems `resource:app` is not supported any more.